# Book about a kid who phases out?

Tags: story-identification

I read a book... Twice... When I was a kid and want to read it again. The problem is I don't remeber the name of it. 
It followed this main character (a boy) who was slowly fading out of his reality. He was still there, but nobody could see him. It's hard to explain, but if this rings any bells for anyone... Let me know the name.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: We're going to need more details, otherwise this question is likely to get closed.

Comment: This... sounds familiar, I think there might be a question here about a similar story.

Comment: You're sure it was a whole book, not a short story? What brings the boys "fading" condition on? How does it end?

Comment: I'm putting this question on hold as **too broad** because there are *many* different stories which fit your description ([here's another example](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/142042/31394)). Please [edit] your question to add more details, following the guide linked by @Edlothiad, and we can get it reopened and answered. Do take the time to go through those checklists - I'm sure you remember more than you think!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you're thinking of ***[The Last Invisible Boy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1416960899)*** by Evan Kuhlman? The main character is a boy who gradually becomes invisible.

[image: The cover of The Last Invisible Boy.]

> Finn Garrett is disappearing. He used to have black hair and
>   skin-colored skin, but each day his hair gets whiter and his skin gets
>   more transparent. It’s been happening since the day his father died,
>   and he can’t figure out how to stop it. Before he vanishes completely,
>   Finn is writing everything down for us, his faithful readers. His
>   words and pictures are the memoirs of The Last Invisible Boy. At turns
>   funny and moving, Evan Kuhlman’s first novel for children, featuring
>   drawings by cartoonist J.P. Coovert, is a magnificent and original
>   tale of love and loss.

Comment: "skin-colored skin."

Comment: Quality - I saw the 'skin coloured skin'  phrase right away as well.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible you're describing *[Fade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fade_(novel))* by Robert Cormier?

[image: Fade - Book Cover]

> In the summer of 1938, the young Paul Moreaux, who lives in a town outside of Boston called Monument, discovers he can "fade," become invisible. His family has had this ability generation after generation; it is passed down from uncle to nephew.
>
> Bewildered and then thrilled with the possibilities of invisibility, Paul experiments with his "gift." He sees things that he should not witness. His power soon overloads him, shows him shocking secrets, pushes him over the edge, and drives him toward some chilling and horrible acts for which there is no forgiveness, no forgetting, and no turning back. Paul discovers how cruel, evil, and disgusting the world can be, and how the ability to fade becomes a nightmare.

It's a somewhat infamous book in that, despite being a book for kids, it depicts murder and incest among the scenes that Paul views. If I recall correctly, part of the reveal involves him not showing up in a picture he knows he was in, and it turns out that he faded in that moment (I think mid-sneeze?).